# Mediawiki job is claimed but not processed

Tags: php, mediawiki

I've been running a wiki for some time and we have the translate extension installed.
This works great, only that there is now a page stuck and we aren't able to translate on that page anymore.

First of all tried this: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T206464
Didn't did the job...

After I read something about looking up the active Jobs and found out that there was a job "stuck"

```
xx@xx[~/public_html/maintenance]$ php showJobs.php --wiki=frwiki --group
TranslatablePageMoveJob: 0 queued; 1 claimed (0 active, 1 abandoned); 0 delayed

xx@xx [~/public_html/maintenance]$ php showJobs.php --wiki=frwiki --group --list
TranslatablePageMoveJob "page_name_x" (id=46762,timestamp=20200621154213) status=claimed
```

Is there anyway to get the job out of the list? So that it's not claimed anymore. Kill or flush it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the radical solution: backup the database, connect to it and run `DELETE FROM job WHERE id = 46762;`.

Comment: Haven't been online here for some time, but this was in the end what I did.